# Install PushWoosh on iOS (PhoneGap/Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, pushwoosh

I'm trying to install PushWoosh, but I don't understand the first instruction here:

https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/

> 1. Install the Plugin source code for Phonegap push notifications into your app by running the following command in the command line:
>      phonegap plugin add
>      https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git

I tried that (copy and pasted it into terminal) and it gave me an error: [error] project directory could not be found

Comment: are you using cordova or phonegap? were you on your project folder when you pasted that command?

Comment: I just tried moving into the root folder for my app. It is PhoneGap and PhoneGap uses Cordova. It successfully added the PushWoosh folder into the plugins folder. I'm not 100% sure if that's where it goes because if you go into platforms > ios > MyAppName, there is a Plugins folder. I guess the PushWoosh website just doesn't specify where to put the framework files. :/

Comment: yes, phonegap uses cordova, but CLI commands aren't the same, that's why I was asking you if you used phonegap or cordova. If the plugin installed without problems, then the files must be where they should, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cordova, just use this other command (as with other cordova plugins):

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git
```